# Как вставить регулярку в селектор jq

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой блок:

```
<div id="key-<?=$key["id"]; ?>"> ... </div>
```

При нажати на кнопку. которая находится в средине кода. удаляется этот блок (Там есть `data-id`, которий я беру с помощью `attr` - `$('#key-${id}').remove();`). После удаления, хочу узнать есть ли еще такие блоки с подобным `id`. Думаю что то через регулярку сделать. 
Думаю что то вроде такого:

`if ($("*").is('#key-${/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]*/}')) { ... }` - но кыдает ошибку

Спасибо

Comment: `После удаления, хочу узнать есть ли еще такие блоки с подобным id` Я не понял, у вас что ли несколько элементов с одинаковыми атрибутами `id` на странице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать без регулярки, с помощью проверки [начала атрибута](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors):

```js
$(function() {
  $('button#del').click(function() {
    $('div').remove();
  });
  $('button#has').click(function() {
    if($('[id^="key-id-"]').length > 0){
      alert('Есть');
    }else{
      alert('Нету');
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="key-id-1">0</div> 
<div id="key-id-2">1</div> 
<div id="key-id-3">2</div> 
<div id="key-id-4">3</div> 
<div id="key-id-5">4</div> 

<button id="del">Удалить</button>
<button id="has">Проверить</button>
```